# Node connections have weird black borders?

Tags: node-editor

So the other day my cat walked across my keyboard and now all the connection lines for my nodes in the node editor have weird black areas around them . . . not sure what it does and would like to be able to return it to normal lol.

Any input is accepted.

blender 2.69[image]

Comment: Any reason you're still on such an old version of Blender?

Comment: ya lol. its my daughters pc and its running xp still cuz for the life of me i cant get 7 to run stable on it. . . . i run 2.78 but still its a something i have yet to see or read about and because of that i have no idea what it does or how to make it go away haha ( still a noob if you couldnt tell) :)

Comment: Running WinXP at this moment is rather irresponsible. Better install one of the flavours of Ubuntu Linux if the hardware doesn't support a newer Windows, it'll run Blender just fine.

Comment: i started teaching my kid about the use of pc's when she was 4 . . . she is 9 now and getting pretty good at it but im not sure im ready to set her up on a linux build or a dual boot yet lol . . . especially because they are also trying to teach her how to operate mac os x at school

Comment: like dont get me wrong i get what your saying and soon with any luck ill have her on a better pc but for now it would be easiest to just figure out what the cat did to cause the black borders around the noodles. So far i havent been able to determine what it is even doing. Like its not stopping things from rendering or anything like that . . . . i just want to know what its purpose is and how to turn it on and off lol. im still pretty noob at this lol and i was hopping to avoid hours and hours of reading documentation to find the solution :)

Comment: Usually I would recommend upgrading your video drivers and Blender, but since that's not an option, maybe try the Interface tab of the User Preferences?